# Apache Cassandra stock data model design

Tags: cassandra, nosql, primary-key, cassandra-3.0, composite-primary-key

I got a lot of data regarding stock prices and I want to try Apache Cassandra out for this purpose. But I'm not quite familiar with the primary/ partition/ clustering keys.

My database columns would be:

```
Stock_Symbol
Price
Timestamp
```

My users will always filter for the Stock_Symbol (where stock_symbol=XX) and then they might filter for a certain time range (Greater/ Less than (equals)). There will be around 30.000 stock symbols.

Also, what is the big difference when using another "filter", e.g. exchange_id (only two stock exchanges are available).

```
Exchange_ID
Stock_Symbol
Price
Timestamp
```

So my users would first filter for the stock exchange (which is more or less a foreign key), then for the stock symbol (which is also more or less a foreign key). The data would be inserted/ written in this order as well.

How do I have to choose the keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Quick Answer

Based on your use-case and predicted query pattern, I would recommend one of the following for your table:

```
PRIMARY KEY (Stock_Symbol, Timestamp)
```

The partition key is made of `Stock_Symbol`, and `Timestamp` is the only clustering column. This will allow `WHERE` to be used with those two fields. If either are to be filtered on, filtering on `Stock_Symbol` will be required in the query and must come as the first condition to `WHERE`.

Or, for the second case you listed:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((Exchange_ID, Stock_Symbol), Timestamp)
```

The partition key is composed of `Exchange_ID` and `Stock_Symbol`, and `Timestamp` is the only clustering column. This will allow `WHERE` to be used with those three fields. If any of those three are to be filtered on, filtering on both `Exchange_ID` and `Stock_Symbol` will be required in the query and must come in that order as the first two conditions to `WHERE`.

See the last section of this answer for a few other variations that could also be applied based on your needs.

### Long Answer & Explanation

**Primary Keys, Partition Keys, and Clustering Columns**

Primary keys in Cassandra, similar to their role in relational databases, serve to identify records and index them in order to access them quickly. However, due to the distributed nature of records in Cassandra, they serve a secondary purpose of *also* determining which node that a given record should be stored on.

The primary key in a Cassandra table is further broken down into two parts - the [Partition Key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/wherePK.html), which is mandatory and by default is the first column in the primary key, and optional [clustering column(s)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/whereClustering.html), which are all fields that are in the primary key that are not a part of the partition key.

Here are some examples:

```
PRIMARY KEY (Exchange_ID)
```

`Exchange_ID` is the sole field in the primary key and is also the partition key. There are no additional clustering columns.

```
PRIMARY KEY (Exchange_ID, Timestamp, Stock_Symbol)
```

`Exchange_ID`, `Timestamp`, and `Stock_Symbol` together form a composite primary key. The partition key is `Exchange_ID` and `Timestamp` and `Stock_Symbol` are both clustering columns.

```
PRIMARY KEY ((Exchange_ID, Timestamp), Stock_Symbol)
```

`Exchange_ID`, `Timestamp`, and `Stock_Symbol` together form a composite primary key. The partition key is composed of both `Exchange_ID` and `Timestamp`. The extra parenthesis grouping `Exchange_ID` and `Timestamp` group them into a single composite partition key, and `Stock_Symbol` is a clustering column.

```
PRIMARY KEY ((Exchange_ID, Timestamp))
```

`Exchange_ID` and `Timestamp` together form a composite primary key. The partition key is composed of both `Exchange_ID` and `Timestamp`. There are no clustering columns.

**But What Do They Do?**

Internally, the partitioning key is used to calculate a token, which determines on which node a record is stored. The clustering columns are not used in determining which node to store the record on, but they are used in determining order of how records are laid out within the node - this is important when querying a range of records. Records whose clustering columns are similar in value will be stored close to each other on the same node; they "cluster" together.

**Filtering in Cassandra**

Due to the distributed nature of Cassandra, fields can only be filtered on if they are indexed. This can be accomplished in a few ways, usually by being a part of the primary key or by having a secondary index on the field. Secondary indexes can cause performance issues [according to DataStax Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html), so it is typically recommended to capture your use-cases using the primary key if possible.

Any field in the primary key can have a `WHERE` clause applied to it (unlike unindexed fields which *cannot* be filtered on in the general case), but there are some stipulations:

- **Order Matters** - The primary key fields in the `WHERE` clause must be in the order that they are defined; if you have a primary key of `(field1, field2, field3)`, you cannot do `WHERE field2 = 'value'`, but rather you must include the preceding fields as well: `WHERE field1 = 'value' AND field2 = 'value'`.
- **The Entire Partition Key Must Be Present** - If applying a `WHERE` clause to the primary key, the entire partition key must be given so that the cluster can determine what node in the cluster the requested data is located in; if you have a primary key of `((field1, field2), field3)`, you cannot do `WHERE field1 = 'value'`, but rather you must include the full partition key: `WHERE field1 = 'value' AND field2 = 'value'`.

**Applied to Your Use-Case**

With the above info in mind, you can take the analysis of how users will query the database, as you've done, and use that information to [design your data model](https://shermandigital.com/blog/designing-a-cassandra-data-model/), or more specifically in this case, the primary key of your table.

You mentioned that you will have about 30k unique values for `Stock_Symbol` and further that it will always be included in `WHERE` cluases. That sounds initially like a resonable candidate for a partition key, as long as queries will include only a single value that they are searching for in `Stock_Symbol` (e.g. `WHERE Stock_Symbol = 'value'` as opposed to `WHERE Stock_Symbol < 'value'`). If a query is intended to return multiple records with multiple values in `Stock_Symbol`, there is a danger that the cluster will need to retrieve data from multiple nodes, which may result in performance penalties.

Further, if your users wish to filter on `Timestamp`, it should also be a part of the primary key, though wanting to filter on a range indicates to me that it probably shouldn't be a part of the partition key, so it would be a good candidate for a clustering column.

This brings me to my recommendation:

```
PRIMARY KEY (Stock_Symbol, Timestamp)
```

If it were important to distribute data based on both the `Stock_Symbol` and the `Timestamp`, you could introduce a pre-calculated time-bucketed field that is based on the time but with less cardinality, such as `Day_Of_Week` or `Month` or something like that:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((Stock_Symbol, Day_Of_Week), Timestamp)
```

If you wanted to introduce another field to filtering, such as `Exchange_ID`, it could be a part of the partition key, which would mandate it being included in filters, or it could be a part of the clustering column, which would mean that it wouldn't be required unless subsequent fields in the primary key needed to be filtered on. As you mentioned that users will always filter by `Exchange_ID` and then by `Stock_Symbol`, it might make sense to do:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((Exchange_ID, Stock_Symbol), Timestamp)
```

Or to make it non-mandatory:

```
PRIMARY KEY (Stock_Symbol, Exchange_ID, Timestamp)
```